# semantic meaning of button color classes

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Zurb Foundation defines several [button color classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/buttons.html): 
Default,Success,Secondary,Alert,Info,Disabled

Unfortunately there is no best practice guide on where to use which classes in an application.

What bothers me, is that the default button has a rather outstanding color. So all buttons in my application look kind of important.

On the other hand, what would be the best class for the submit button of a form? Should it be the default button, because submitting is the default action? Than I'd need to add the "secondary" class to all other buttons to let the submit button stand out.

But I don't like to add the "secondary" class everywhere.

Am I missing something? Does anybody have good best practice examples of foundation class usage?

Answer (score 1):

Default takes the colors of the primary color (`$primary-color` in the SCSS file) while secondary takes `$secondary-color`. It's because you changed the primary color that they stand out for you.

They are defined here (these are defaults):

```
$primary-color: #008CBA;
$secondary-color: #e7e7e7;
$alert-color: #f04124;
$success-color: #43AC6A;
$warning-color: #f08a24;
$info-color: #a0d3e8;
```

You can make your own button colors/class with SCSS.

```
.custom-button-class {
  @include button(
    // $padding - Used to build padding for buttons Default: $button-med or rem-calc(12)
    $padding,
    // Background color. We can set $bg:false for a transparent background. Default: $primary-color.
    $bg,
    // If true, set to button radius which is $global-radius or explicitly set radius amount in px (ex. $radius:10px). Default:false.
    $radius,
    // We can set $full-width:true to remove side padding extend width. Default:false
    $full-width,
    // We can set $disabled:true to create a disabled transparent button. Default:false
    $disabled
  );
}
```